# PyGame window refuses to open. Crashes on line "screen = display.set_mode([800, 500])"

Tags: python, pygame

The PyGame window isn't opening and I have no idea why. What I do know is that "screen = display.set_mode([800, 500])" is the line the code starts glitching. Here is the code:

```
from pygame import *
from pygame.event import *

init()
screen = display.set_mode([800, 500])
RED = (255,0,0)
mousedown = False

while True:
    for event in get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousedown = True
    if mousedown:
        location = mouse.get_pos()
        draw.circle(screen, RED, location, 20)
        display.update()
```

I'm on Mac OS Catalina and the Python version is 3.8. I also don't know if I installed PyGame wrong.

EDIT: The code works perfectly fine on repl.it PyGame editor if that would help anyone here answer the question.

Comment: Crashes how? Do you have a traceback?

Comment: I figured out why @cricket_007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that PyGame 1.9.6 doesn't run with Python 3.8 on Mac so I just had to run:

```
pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

In terminal.